# Rails 4, Unknown action, The action 'destroy' could not be found for PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

What is usually a simple error with a simple solution, I seem to be stuck:

**posts#controller:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
 @posts = Post.all
end

def show
 @post = Post.find params[:id]
end

def new
 @post = Post.new
end

def create
 @post = Post.create post_params

 if @post.save
  redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post was saved!"
 else
  render 'new'
 end

end

private
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
 end

def edit
 @post = Post.find params[:id]
end

def update
 @post = Post.find params[:id]

 if @post.update_attributes params[:post]
  redirect_to posts_path
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end

def destroy
 @post = Post.find params[:id]
 @post.destroy

 redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been deleted"
end

end
```

routes.rb:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

 resources :posts

end
```

rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
      POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
      PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
      PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
      DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

posts view, index.html.slim:

```
h1 Blog
- @posts.each do |post|
 h2 = link_to post.title, post
 p = post.content
 p = link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post)
 p = link_to 'Delete', post, :confirm => "Are you sure?", method: :delete
 br

p = link_to 'Add a new post', new_post_path
```

Yet I continue to get an error inside the browser showing:

*Unknown action, The action 'destroy' could not be found for PostsController*

I seem to be getting a few of these basic problems since I updated to Rails 4, probably a minor oversight, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the top line of your controller and the relevant part of your routes file?

Comment: plz show, how u r calling destroy method from ur view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PostsController#destroy` is under your `private` declaration, so it's a [private method](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Private) -- there are restrictions on how it can be called.

Try moving `def destroy ... end` above the word `private` (and protecting that route another way, if appropriate).  If for some reason you still need to call a private method, you can use `#send`, for example:

```
PostsController.new.send :destroy # and any arguments, comma-separated
```

(Using `#send` this way makes no sense for a Rails controller, but it might come in handy another time!)

Answer (score 0):

In posts_controller.rb, try using this code

```html
def destroy
  Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

And in index.html.erb use

```html
<%= link_to "Delete", post, :data => {:confirm => "Are you sure?"}, :method => :delete %>
```

Figured it out using rails 4.2.5.1. I think this is rails 4.x specific but it might work on other versions.